# Assembly routine to add matrices not giving expected output

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, masm

I am writing an assembly routine that adds two 2D matrices. The code is written in MASM syntax.

```
; --------------------
; matrixAdd.asm
; --------------------

; Adds two matrices

; extern "C" int matrixAdd(int *matrixOnePtr, int *matrixTwoPtr, long long rows, long long cols)

    .code
matrixAdd proc frame
    ; function prologue
    push r12                                                    ; push r12 register for use
    .pushreg r12
    push r13                                                    ; push r13 register for use
    .pushreg r13
    push r14                                                    ; push r14 register for use
    .pushreg r14
    .endprolog
    
    ; validate number of rows and columns
    cmp r8, 0                                                   ; compare rows 
    jle InvalidArg                                              ; jump to InvalidArg if rows <= 0
                                        
    cmp r9, 0                                                   ; compare cols
    jle InvalidArg                                              ; jump to InvalidArg if cols <= 0

    xor r10, r10                                                ; set r10 (increment variable) to 0

LoopOne:
    xor r11, r11                                                ; set r11 (inner increment variable) to 0

LoopTwo:
    mov r12, rcx                                                ; move first pointer to r12
    mov r13, rdx                                                ; move second pointer to r13

    ; calculate offset
    mov r14, r10                                                ; move r10 (outer increment variable) to r14
    imul r14, r9                                                ; multiply r14 by number of columns
    add r14, r11                                                ; add inner increment variable
    imul r14, 4                                                 ; multiply offset by 4

    add r12, r14                                                ; add offset to first pointer
    add r13, r14                                                ; add offset to second pointer

    mov r14, [r13]                                              ; move value of second pointer to r14
    add [r12], r14                                              ; add two matrices

    inc r11                                                     ; increment inner increment variable
    cmp r11, r9                                                 ; compare inner increment variable to columns
    jle LoopTwo                                                 ; jump if r11 <= cols

    ; LoopOne; check if outer increment variable is <= rows
    inc r10                                                     ; increment outer increment variable
    cmp r10, r8                                                 ; compare r10 to rows
    jle LoopOne                                                 ; jump if r10 <= rows

    pop r12                                                     ; restore r12 register
    pop r13                                                     ; restore r13 register
    pop r14                                                     ; restore r14 register
    xor eax, eax                                                ; set successful return code
    ret                                                         ; return 0

; Rows or columns is invalid
InvalidArg:
    pop r12                                                     ; restore r12 register
    pop r13                                                     ; restore r13 register
    pop r14                                                     ; restore r14 register
    mov eax, 1                                                  ; move 1 into eax register
    ret                                                         ; return 1
matrixAdd endp  
    end
```

The main function is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int matrixAdd(int *matrixOnePtr, int *matrixTwoPtr, long long rows, long long cols);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int a1[3][3] = {
        {1, 2, 3},
        {1, 2, 3},
        {1, 2, 3}
    };

    int a2[3][3] = {
        {1, 2, 3},
        {1, 2, 3},
        {1, 2, 3}
    };

    matrixAdd(a1, a2, 3, 3);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
            printf("%d ", a1[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The expected output should be

```
2 4 6
2 4 6
2 4 6
```

But the result is

```
2 6 9
4 8 9
4 8 9
```

I have been trying to debug the code but it is not working. My computer is Windows 10 64-bit. Each of the matrices are 3x3. I am new to x86 assembly programming.

Comment: For starters, you use `r11 <= cols` when in fact you don't want the `=`. Same for rows. Second, you use 64 bit addition while your array items are 32 bit. Not sure why your debugging did not show this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your (assembly language) algorithm is fundamentally inferior.
  Apparently, you were merely translating two nested loops (as it is customary and correct in HLLs).
  You are forgetting the fact, though, that `int[6][7]` is, with respect to memory, equivalent to an `int[42]`.
  Considering you want to perform matrix *addition*, a series of `rows * cols` sums is more efficient.
- Also, it will simplify address calculating.
  For (mere) address calculation, by the way, you usually use the `lea` instruction.
  Don’t worry, as a novice it can be an intimidatingly complex instruction, for me it was too.
- You are loading the “first/second pointer to r12/r13” *within* the loop.
  This is wrong (or at least unnecessary since you aren’t overwriting `rcx`/`rdx`).
  You should do this exactly once, i. e. outside the loop(s).
- As [Jester](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71065939/assembly-routine-to-add-matrices-not-giving-expected-output#comment125626898_71065939) already commented:
  Because of zero-based indexing of arrays the abort conditions should not include `=`.
  For instance, in the case of an `int[3]` you want to iterate over the set `{0, 1, 2}`.
- Also as [Jester](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71065939/assembly-routine-to-add-matrices-not-giving-expected-output#comment125626898_71065939) already commented, and **this  is the main problem**:
  `mov r14, [r13]` and
  `add [r12], r14`
  will retrieve and operate on a *64‑bit* quantity.
  The size of the destination register in a `mov` is important.
  `mov r14d, [r13]` will retrieve a “double word”, i. e. a 32‑bit quantity.
  Likewise, `add dword ptr [r12], r14d` will add two 32‑bit values.
  Note that the memory address (on a 64‑bit system) always needs to be specified as a *full* 64‑bit register.
  The `dword ptr` prefix will inform MASM about the memory operand size so it’s assembled differentlty.
- The result in `a1[0][0]` is actually correct, because the x86 architecture is a little Endian system.
- Your `pop` instructions at the (two possible) end(s) of the routine must be in the *reverse* `push` order.
  Your code is actually swapping the contents of `r12` and `r14` in the call site context.
  Ideally you would merge both function epilogues, but tackle one problem at a time.
- Lastly, your function *is* returning a (non-constant) `int` value, but your C code is not checking on that.
  Declaring your function `void` is probably the easiest solution.